# Android zoom canvas in and out on surface view with multiple bit maps drawn with onDraw()

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, scale, surfaceview

I have a canvas / surfaceview that I am drawing multiple bitmaps so that the user is able to drag around and position anywhere on the canvas. I am looking for a method to create a zoom in and out button that toggles a 50% zoom scale of the canvas when selected.

My app draws multiple bitmaps to the canvas using the onDraw() method.

I have a function now that scales each individual bitmap when the zoom button is toggled but the problem with this is getting the bitmaps to line up relative to each other after the scale. I currently have them scaled off their ending x/y position but by reducing the size 50% the items that were once near each other are no longer that way when zoomed out. I am hoping there is a solution that allows me to accomplish this with the entire canvas at once.

If I need to share some code please let me know.

SurfaceView class where all the drawing happens

`public class BuildView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {`

then non-scaling drawing happens as `canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap,x,y,null);`

Here is my oncreate method, note that BuildView gameView; is initating my surfaceview class;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set full screen view
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

     FrameLayout Game = new FrameLayout(this);
     LinearLayout GameWidgets = new LinearLayout (this);
     gameview = new BuildView(this, null);         
     //create buttons to lay over the surfaceview
     Button AddItemButton = new Button(this);
     //Button ZoomInButton = new Button(this);
     zoomButton = new Button(this);
     TextView MyText = new TextView(this);
     AddItemButton.setWidth(250);
     AddItemButton.setText("Add Item");
     AddItemButton.setId(1);
     AddItemButton.setOnClickListener(addItemHandler);
     MyText.setText("test");
     zoomButton.setWidth(250);
     zoomButton.setText("Zoom Out");
     zoomButton.setId(2);
     zoomButton.setOnClickListener(zoomHandler);
     // adding views to the main Game framelayout view * note the view "gameview" is the surface view that everything happens on
     GameWidgets.addView(AddItemButton); 
     GameWidgets.addView(zoomButton);
     Game.addView(gameview);
     Game.addView(GameWidgets); 

    int w=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()-25;
    int h=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-25;
    gameview.wid = w; //set width and height in view
    gameview.hei = h;
    gameview.setWidthHeight(w, h);
    setContentView(Game); //trying this out
    gameview.updateImage(0, 0); //force bg change
    Log.i("views", "Added Game View");
    //setContentView(v);
}
```

since it has been requested here is how I am currently scaling the bitmaps, note that I am looking for another method of scaling the entire canvas. Here is the specifics of my onDraw() method but the full method has more logic in regards to item placement and before scaling I check a boolean flag if the user has selected to scale but i figured you wouldn't want to sift through that much code so I am just putting the pertinent stuff here.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
  float scaleHeight = getScaled(myBitmap.getHeight());
  float scaleWidth = getScaled(myBitmap.getWidth());                        

  scaler.postTranslate(-myBitmap.getWidth() / 4, -itemBit.getHeight() / 4); // Centers image
  scaler.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
  Log.e("onDraw", "item not placed - scaler.postTranslate being called");
  scaler.postTranslate(itemX+myBitmap.getWidth()/2, itemY+myBitmap.getHeight()/2);
  canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, scaler, null);
}
```

here is my getScaled function;

```
    float getScaled(int orig) {
    //return a scaled version
    int newScale = orig /2;
        float scaled = ((float) newScale) / orig;                           
    return scaled;
}
```

Comment: Post the code responsible for doing the rescaling so others may be able to help.

Comment: I am not currently re-scaling the canvas, I have a method of scaling the bitmaps but I do not want to use that method. I am just using a matrix scaler for that. I am wanting to instead scale the entire canvas not just a single bitmap. Thanks.

Comment: Just edited to include my onCreate() method and the onDraw() method of my surfaceView.